# php curl to get data from url based on total no of records

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, jira

I am connecting to rest api which gives me json data with only 50 results at a time and i save the result in a variable ,but i want to retrieve 20000 records and  i would like to know how i can build dynamic url to get all the data and save that in a variable.

Below is my current code

```
    $url = "https://org.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=PS+order+by+key&startAt=0";
    $ch = curl_init();

    $headers = array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json');


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $ch_error = curl_error($ch);

            if ($ch_error) {
            echo "cURL Error: $ch_error";
            } else {
            $json = json_decode($result, true);}
```

In my url i have parameter to specify from which number i can return records like first request will be startAt=0 and second would be startAt=51 and thits would be startAt=101 or can i use a formula like x = total no of records/50 and then run curl x times and save all the result in variable or save all the json array and then merge it.Request you to help me on the same.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a query parameter called `maxResults` which defaults to 50. You can specify a higher number.

> maxResults (int): the maximum number of issues to return (defaults to 50). The maximum allowable value is dictated by the JIRA property 'jira.search.views.default.max'. If you specify a value that is higher than this number, your search results will be truncated.

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/search-search

Comment: unfortunately this option is not available for on demand version of jira

Answer (score 0):

I created a loop for this and resolved the problem.